# Changing field order in Infopath

Tags: infopath

I have a SharePoint form that is published in InfoPath. The form has several fields such as Name, Address, Phone Number etc. 
Can the order of the forms be modified in InfoPath?
I tried using SharePoint but when I make the change in SharePoint, InfoPath does not pick up the changes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the layout of the IP form you need to use IP designer .
Infopath doesn't take into account the sequence set up in Sharepoint(only does it inially when you create form for a list) (in fact it can have more fields if you are using IP library than library itself, as not all fields need to be promoted to Sharepoint library.